# Math.Round double .5

Tags: c#, double, rounding

Let say:

```
Math.Round(2.5) //2.0
Math.Round(-2.5) //-2.0
Math.Round(2.5,MidpointRounding.ToEven) // 2.0
Math.Round(2.5,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) //3.0
```

Question: if I change the number with -77777777.5 why the result is -77777778.0 not -77777777.0

```
Math.Round(-77777777.5) // -77777778.0
Math.Round(-77777777.5,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) // -77777778.0
Math.Round(-77777777.5,MidpointRounding.ToEven) // -77777778.0
```

Comment: If you want to round down, use Math.Floor

Comment: No, i don't want to round it down. I want to rounding .5 to 0

Comment: What do you want to be result if the number is `-77777777.467`?

Comment: @ Farhad Jabiyev : i want that result will be `-77777777.0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default [`MidPointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) mode is `ToEven`. In this mode, as explained by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx) (where `a` is the input value),

> The integer nearest a. If the fractional component of a is halfway
>   between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the
>   even number is returned.

`-77777777.5` has two nearest integers `-77777777` and `-77777778` but the latter is the even one so that is the one that is returned.

In the `AwayFromZero` mode, `-77777778` is clearly further from zero than `-77777777`.

Comment: and then why `Math.Round(2.5) //2.0` return 2.0 not 3.0 ?
it's make me confuse

Comment: @Husnan `2.5` has two nearest integers `2` and `3`. Of those, `2` is even, so in the `ToEven` mode that is the one that is returned. `2` is also closer to zero, so in the `AwayFromZero` mode, `2` is returned again.

Comment: CORRECTION: `3` is clearly further from zero than `2` so the result of `Math.Round(2.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` is `3`, not `2` as I originally commented.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of rounding (not specifying MidPointRounding just means that it takes the default option, which is ToEven). The type of rounding determines what happens with 0.5.

Away from zero: like it says, it rounds to the number 'away from the zero' (so to the bigger absolute number). E.g.:

```
2.5 -> 3
1.5 -> 2
0.5 -> 1
-0.5 -> -1
-1.5 -> -2
-2.5 -> -3
```

To even: like it says, it rounds to the nearest even number. E.g.:

```
2.5 -> 2
1.5 -> 2
0.5 -> 0
-0.5 -> 0
-1.5 -> -2
-2.5 -> -2
```

EDIT: It seems what you want it 'Towards Zero' rounding. As far as I'm aware, that is not an option in C#.

EDIT 2: Since the default C# methods offer no help, you'll have write a custom function. [Here](http://www.jackleitch.net/2010/06/adventures-in-net-rounding-part-2-exotic-rounding-algorithms/) you can find an interesting blog about different rounding methods. I have not tested it myself, but this is what is suggested for a towards zero rounding:

```
public static int RoundToNearestRoundHalfTowardZero(decimal value)
{
    // If value is non-negative, subtract 0.5 and take the next
    // greater integer. If value is negative, add 0.5 and take the
    // next lower integer.
    if (value >= 0)
        return (int)Math.Ceiling(value - 0.5m);
    else
        return (int)Math.Floor(value + 0.5m);
}
```

Comment: Yes.. there is no option in c#.
What i want is when double is negative it towards zero.

Comment: @Husnan I added a custom function that might give you what you want.